# How to find rows in matrix with specific number of consecutive 0s and 1s in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0 
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0   
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0   
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

What I want to do is to filter this matrix by rows where the minimum number of consecutive 0s and 1s is n.

For example, if `n = 2`, the expected output should be this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0 
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0     
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

As you can see the rows 1, 2 and 6 of the initial matrix had a minimum of only one consecutive 1, one consecutive 0 and one consecutive 0, respectively.

If `n = 3`, the expected output should be an empty matrix since no row has a minimum of three consecutive 0s and three consecutive 1s simultaneously.

Is there a way to create a function that takes as input a matrix and the value n and gives the expected output in R?

This is the matrix of the example:

```
matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
         0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,   
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,   
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), byrow = T, ncol = 8)
```

Comment: You problem can be solved with `diff()` and then comparison of both matrices. For more details, please enter R the code that created your examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rle` row-wise and select the rows where the minimum consecutive length between numbers is at least `n`.

```
n <- 2
mat[apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(rle(x)$lengths >= n)), ]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

**data**

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = 7:8)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create the condition for subsetting the rows

```
library(data.table)
n <- 2
mat[apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(table(rleid(x))>=2)),]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
```

#### data

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = 7:8)
```